# Can't run nodetool on my vagrant virtual cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, vagrant, nodetool

Basically I'm trying to run a simple two node virtual cassandra cluster to experiment with. I'm trying to set it up so all I need to do is run `vagrant up` and have cassandra up and running.

I've managed to get the actual cluster working (I know this because in one node I create a keyspace and table and inserted a value into it which I was able to access from the other node) but I can't seem to get nodetool to work.

When I run

```
nodetool -h 192.168.10.11 -p 7000 status
```

I get the error

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '192.168.10.11:7000' - SocketException: 'Connection reset'.
```

The reason I've changed ports around is to avoid port collisions. (So I changed the jmx_port to 7000 for one node and 7001 for another, I also changed the rpc_port and native_transport_port so that each node is using a unique port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what I needed to fix to get nodetool working.

Firstly you don't need to modify the jmx port setting at all. You also don't need to expose it as a forwarded_port.

Now on how to actually get it working:

In cassandra-env.sh there is a line that is commented out that says:

```
#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname>
```

Uncomment this line and put either the hostname or ip of the node you want nodetool to connect from or the node you want to connect to. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

For people who still have problems to get Cassandra running on vagrant using Ubuntu, I want to share my shell script what install Java8 and Cassandra. Maybe it helps:

```
# Update Packages
sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get upgrade -y

# Install necassary software
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties debconf-utils curl --assume-yes

# Installing the Oracle Java Virtual Machine
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default -y 

# Installing Cassandra
curl -L http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dsc22=2.2.7-1 cassandra=2.2.7 -y
sudo apt-get install cassandra-tools=2.2.7 -y
sudo chmod 750 /var/run/cassandra
# Configure hostname or ip for nodetool
sudo sed -i 's@# JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>"@JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"@' /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
sleep 10

# Status Cassandra And Oracle Java Version
java -version
sudo service cassandra status
sudo nodetool status
```